# BigQuery UI - Datasets missing

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a weird issue with my BigQuery UI (going on https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/queries/my-project-name).  I don't know why, but I see no datasets for my projects, when I'm fully aware they exist. My code can still hit these datasets and their tables. There is just no way for me to see them.

In the UI itself, I can still query them if I type the whole query by hand, but being able to see my structure for my schema could be helpful.

When I check my network tab in the developer tools on chrome, I notice that I receive "Failed to load ressource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS". I then decided to do everything I could to reset my own cache. I cleared my cookies, went incognito, I tried other browsers, even other computers. NOTHING brings back my datasets.

Anyone encountered this and has any ideas how to force my cache to hit?

Comment: did you reload? what are the actual names?

Comment: I tried different browsers and machines, and I also did refresh multiple times. If you think I may have some weird characters, I'm aware of the issue with underscores, so I made sure not to use any :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem a while back. When I got the error, I struggled with it and I ended up finding a way to reset this. Seems like it's something cached server-side that makes this incorrect cache-hit. The way to reset the server-side cache is to hit a URL with a project that doesn't exist, so something like https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/queries/bogus-nonexistant-project  should reset it all

Answer (score 3):

Did you recently assign a new string ID to your project that previously only had a numeric ID?  If so, this is a known issue that has been reported recently, and I'm still working to resolve.

The issue is that the frontend cache gets stuck with the old numeric ID for the project and our frontend JS has a bug where it errors out instead of updating the cache to contain the new string ID.  LiY's workaround of going to a bogus, uncacheable URL is the suggested workaround to unstick the cache until this bug is resolved.

(And if you didn't recently assign a new string ID to your project, then I'd love to hear more details about what might have caused this issue so it won't happen to anyone else!)

Comment: Actually that was done recently on the project. It's nice to understand what the actual problem is :) thank you for your input