# BigQuery dataset exists but none of its tables get listed - server cache bug?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a weird issue which is almost certainly a bug.
In BQ I have a dataset which I know for a fact has tables and views.
However, none of these tables/views are visible.
When I load the page I see the little triangle next to it for a second and then it disappears.

I can click on it and see dataset info.
I can get a complete metadata list of tables when I query the dataset .INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.
I can query any of the tables/views under the dataset if I write the queries myself.
I can even see all of them when I use the Classic UI.

There's a 404 error in my Chrome dev tools which I think relates to it:[image]

I've tried the "bogus" project load (referenced here [BigQuery UI - Datasets missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226932/bigquery-ui-datasets-missing)) to try and fix server side cache to no avail.

My whole team can't see it and tried different browsers too so it's definitely server-side.

I think the bug is caused by the BigQuery Data Transfer Service, creating a scheduled query specifically.

That's because the "Last modified" time of my dataset coincides perfectly with the time the BQ DTS ran the dataservice.update method on the dataset when creating a new scheduled query. 
According to the documentation this method replaces the whole dataset resource (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/update).
My theory is that the transfer service does an update which essentially creates a new dataset (different id) but the old one is somehow cached serverside which is why I can't see it in the UI anymore.

Has anybody come across the same issue?

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: We experience the same issue. Your Classic UI workaround helps at the moment. There is 1 person in our team, however, that still can see all tables in the affected dataset.

Comment: @vvasch We had one person that could see the dataset too - the person that created the scheduled query which I think "broke" the dataset. He created the query on Wednesday when we all stopped seeing the dataset (except him). He had access by Friday still but seems to have lost it as well this morning (Monday).

Comment: @GeorgeS, can you open BigQuery UI in a incognito window to check if you still can not see your tables? Sometimes, some extensions have conflict with BigQuery.

Comment: To look into this issue would require your project id, to allow inspection of what is going on. But you will need to open a support case as you cannot expose your project id on a public forum such as this

Comment: @PaddyPopeye I've sent details of this via the "Send feedback" link - is that the best way? I also looked for any bug reports on this but couldn't find any. Will try and add it to the buganizer when I have some time.

Comment: you can open a support case by navigating to 'Support' from within your project's console

Comment: @PaddyPopeye Thanks, that's not ideal though as have to pay for it. Our organisation has a confusing billing structure so it will take me ages to get to the right people to get budget to pay for support.

Comment: @GeorgeS, It seems to be fixed. We can now see all tables in the affected dataset again. We did nothing from our end.

Comment: @vvasch same here but not sure if it was actually fixed or the server-side cache expired. Will comment here if we get the issue again.